# Chrome Web Developer Tools - Ignore scripts while step debugging

Tags: google-chrome

I used to add scripts to the ignore list (blacklist) by right clicking on them and selecting something like "Ignore this script".

But in my chrome version, it seems like they removed that feature and you have to add them manually to the ignore list.

If I right click on the script, then the option to add it to the ignore list, is no longer there.

[image]

Was it removed or do I need to enable something in the settings to make it show up?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You have to right click into the script:

[image: Add script to ignore list]